# fill 5 boxes of a table randomly containing 20 boxes

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a table which has 20 boxes, and i must color 5 of them by clicking on a button, the problem is that I must color 5 boxes randomly and not the entire table.
Can you please help me

```
    $(bluecolor);
    function bluecolor() {
        $(".boutton2").click(function () {
            $("div>div>div").each(function () {
                $(this).addClass("blue");

            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Show the HTML since nothing in your code is a "table" reference as noted in your question, please be clear, complete and precise.

Comment: I created my table with  5 div in 4 div, which makes 20 div, all 4 div are in 1 big div. I color 5random div in blue (work now) and I created a function which colors in green the divs i clicked on it. If blue divs was green, than it should colors them in orange.

Comment: If you add a class as in my answer example to the "inner" div set (the 20 in the 5X4 matrix then it should work.  The other click/color events would be a different and simple thing to do IF you need help with that, there are probably instances of those type things already in questions.

Comment: Not sure what your `$(bluecolor);` is about (creating a jQuery object) there . But it would really seem to be that you can simply remove that function wrapper of the click event handler.

Comment: well thanks, I'll see more maybe on the others questions

Comment: I modified the answer to reflect the color toggles, using three classes - better than explicit "color" named classes perhaps.  Note you could also "do this once" by changing the "button" to only trigger the event "once" by changing the `.on(` to `.one(` for that button event handler IF that is needed, not sure your requirement there.

Comment: I didn't find how to addclass Orange if my div has blue and green class
        function bluecolor() { 
            $(".boutton2").click(function () {
                    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        var rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
                        $("#" + rn).addClass("blue");
                    }
                    if("div" .green .blue == true){
                        $("div" .green .blue).addClass("orange");
                    }
                });
            }
it's like the if condition is ignored, and i can't addClass

Comment: This adds the third class with the orange color `$("#mytablething").on('click','.second-color',function() {
  //clear existing
  $(this).removeClass('second-color').addClass('third-color');
});` when it has the second color...i.e. if you click green you get orange

Comment: Note your `if("div" .green .blue == true)` is invalid code syntax and NOT a selector.

Comment: Also note "Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start with a letter for compatibility." ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id Study up on selectors https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: how can I fix it with an if condition ? Because I don't undersatnd with others functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get 5 random numbers, which are chosen from 1 to 20 and accordingly change the background colors of the cells/divs using ids.

For example like this:

```
for(i=0; i<5, i++){
    var rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    $('#'+ rn).css({"background-color":"blue"});
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, it doesn't work $("div>div>div" + rn).css({"background-color": "blue"}); shoud work ? no ?

Comment: No, you have to have a div for each cell of the table and give each div an id. For example: `<div id="1">`
If the random number chosen is 1, then this div will have it's color changed. So, you have to give the ids from 1 to 20 to the divs, which wrap the individual cells. 
The code, which I posted doesn't need to be changed then.

Comment: No problem. I hope, it answered your question and solved your problem.

Comment: Note that this solution might actually color the same box randomly thus missing some number less than 5.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing here is to break it down to show the creation of the random number and randomly add the class to some div within a group of div.  I used a class `boxthing` to demonstrate the "group" which I used a simple recursive function to do that to.

Simply click the button to randomly color a new group.

**Modified to illustrate a "first, second, third" color and a "static" layout.**

```js
var maxNumber = 20;

function createDivs(num) {
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    $('#mytablething').append('<div class="boxthing">' + i + '</div>');
  }
}
// commented out on revision 
// createDivs(maxNumber);

// Returns a random integer between min (included) and max (excluded)
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
// add blue to some random N number of divs
function doBlue(n) {
  if ($('.boxthing.first-color').length < n) {
    var boxnumber = getRandomInt(0, maxNumber);
    $("div.boxthing").eq(boxnumber).addClass("first-color");
    doBlue(n);
  }
  return "done";
}
$("#mybutton").on('click',function() {
  //clear existing classes
  $('.boxthing').removeClass('first-color second-color third-color');
  doBlue(5);
});
$("#mytablething").on('click','.first-color',function() {
  //clear existing
  $(this).removeClass('first-color').addClass('second-color');
});
$("#mytablething").on('click','.second-color',function() {
  //clear existing
  $(this).removeClass('second-color').addClass('third-color');
});
```

```css
#mytablething div.row{border:solid red 1px; height: 1em; width:6em;}
#mytablething div.boxthing {
  border: solid cyan 1px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display:inline-block;
}

.first-color {
  background-color: blue;
}
.second-color {
  background-color: green;
}
.third-color {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mybutton">Start</button>
<div id="mytablething">
    <div class="row"><div class='boxthing'></div><div class='boxthing'></div><div class='boxthing'></div><div class='boxthing'></div></div>
    <div class="row"><div class='boxthing'></div><div class='boxthing'></div><div class='boxthing'></div><div class='boxthing'></div></div>
    <div class="row"><div class='boxthing'></div><div class='boxthing'></div><div class='boxthing'></div><div class='boxthing'></div></div>
    <div class="row"><div class='boxthing'></div><div class='boxthing'></div><div class='boxthing'></div><div class='boxthing'></div></div>
    <div class="row"><div class='boxthing'></div><div class='boxthing'></div><div class='boxthing'></div><div class='boxthing'></div></div>
</div>
```